# Extract parameters from variable length python f-string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.6

I have an f-string in `main` that looks like

```
title =f'Backup errors in {folder} on {host} at {datetime.datetime.today()}'
```

used in the following function call `send_mail(title, message, to, from)`

I am not allowed to change the function call.

The question is, inside `send_email` can I extract the `folder`, and `host` variables from the f-string?

I would normally try something like:

```
extracted_folder = title.split()[17:30]
```

but `folder` and `host` are both going to be variable length.

Comment: I understand you’re not allowed to change the function call; presumably for back-compat reasons(?).  However, adding a `**kwargs` argument will allow the two additional values to be passed in, without creating compatibility issues.

Comment: One the f-string is built, it’s just that, a normal string; therefore the fields used to create the string cannot be re-extracted.  Perhaps regex might be an option?

Comment: Where are `folder` and `host` defined in the first place? Why do you  need to extract them from `title` instead of just using them directly?

Comment: @chepner Folder and host come from another function, and are used here for nefarious purposes, then put into the title of the email.  I was asked to add them to the body of the email. Knowing this company, at a later date, I will be asked to make an extractor that scans an email's body, and extracts that information, probably to Excel.

Comment: But they are *available* inside `send_email`, or you wouldn't be able to construct the string in the first place. If you need to extract them somewhere *else*, where `folder` and `host` are no longer available, that's not *inside `send_email`*.

Comment: @chepner `folder` and `host` are returns from a third function `pretend_name`.  The f-string is built in `main`, then shipped to `send_email`.  Inside `send_email` I need to extract the values once inside `send_email`.

Comment: Oh, so you only have the *value* of `title` in `send_email`, not the f-string literal that *created* that value.

Comment: Yes sir.  I updated the question to better show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do a combination of split and slice like this :

```
title = 'Backup errors in folder 1234 on host1234 at today1234'
folder = title[17:].split(' on ')[-2]
host = title[17:].split(' on ')[-1].split(' at ')[0]
print(folder)
print(host)
```

output :

```
folder 1234
host1234
```

I also work with spaces and with " on " in the folder name if you do an other trick :

```
title = 'Backup errors in folder on 1234 on host1234 at today1234'
folder = " on ".join(title[17:].split(' on ')[:-1])
host = title[17:].split(' on ')[-1].split(' at ')[0]
print(folder)
print(host)
```

output :

```
folder on 1234
host1234
```

Comment: This sort of thing will probably work in practice but makes some assumptions on folder names (e.g. that they can't contain spaces)

Comment: It also work if it contain spaces. I updated to show that you can use space

Comment: Not if they contain `' on '`

Comment: This'll work, thank you.

Comment: Updated to include " on " in the foldername

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module. E.g.:

```py
import re

# regular expression version of text for matching
retext = r'Backup errors in (?P<folder>\S+) on (?P<hostname>\S+) at'

# string containing information
text = 'Backup errors in myfolder on myhost at 17:23:45'

# get dictionary containing the parts of your text
info = re.match(retext, text).groupdict()

print(info)
{'folder': 'myfolder', 'hostname': 'myhost'}
```

Comment: This is clever.

Comment: re is magic! But it's very obscure magic and I can't claim to know a fraction of its full potential.

Answer (score 1):

If folder and host are sigle words (no spaces):

```
>>> title = "Backup errors in /var/mail/filename.log on myserver.domain at ..."
>>> words = title.split(' ')
>>> words[3]
'/var/mail/filename.log'
>>> words[5]
'myserver.domain'
```